# Exclude folder from Analyze > Run Inspection by Name

Tags: intellij-idea, code-analysis, intellij-14, code-inspection

Is it possible to **exclude a folder** when I want to analyze the code in IntelliJ IDEA?

Usage example:

> Analyze > Run Inspection by Name... > Missorted modifiers

It founds a lot of results, but some of them are from folders that contain generated Java files. I want to exclude those Java files.

**Attempts:**

I could find it neither here:

[image]

nor in

> File > Settings...

**Details:**

- IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3
- Windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a Custom Scope.
[image]